# Magento 2 order item find assigned MSI source

Tags: magento2, inventory, msi, multi-source-inventory

I am looking for a extended functionality of Magento 2 adminhtml.

After **order** has been placed (created), how do I find out **origin MSI source for each order item** (and specified quantity)

=> **from which MSI source** items have been reserved/written off?

Do I need to somehow save this information myself during observer/plugin before/after order save event? Or **how does MSI works with this information**?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello @lubos Do you find a solution for it?

Comment: Hi @DavidDuong we simulated what MSI does - it calls some methods for getting available sources etc...